# How to configure KDiff3 for merging Git conflicts?

Tags: git, merge

I have just begun a massive merge in Git, which has created dozens of conflicts within the complex directory structure of my local repo.  To resolve these conflicts, I'd like to try to use KDiff3.  I installed it, and executed the following commands verbatim:

```
git config --global merge.tool kdiff3

git config --global mergetool.kdiff3.cmd '"C:\\Program Files\\KDiff3\\kdiff3 $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE -o $MERGED"'
```

I think I am supposed to substitute something for `$BASE` `$LOCAL` etc., but can find nothing helpful on-line as to what literal values I need to use there.

Now when I run `git mergetool`, I get this output:

> Normal merge conflict for '.gitignore':
>     {local}: modified file 
>     {remote}: modified file
>   Hit return to start merge resolution tool (kdiff3):
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Git/libexec/git-core/mergetools/kdiff3: line 132:
>   C:\Pro gram Files\KDiff3\kdiff3 $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE -o $MERGED: No such file or directory
>   .gitignore seems unchanged.
>   Was the merge successful? [y/n] n

Can anyone explain with concrete examples how this command needs to be formatted for `kdiff` to actually open up with its pretty graphical 3-way merge?

Thank you.

Comment: Use p4merge, that's easier to use ;-)